# Django admin remove choose options from field for staff user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm developing Django application with 2 types of users:

- Admin as super user and
- Reporter as staff user.

In backend both users can add Match report. Admin is able to create report for every club. I would like for Reporter just to have ability to choose clubs only if he is reporter for the club.

Inside model Club is fields with reporter. One reporter can be reporter for 1 or more clubs.

I have problem with removing clubs where reporter is not reporter for club?
How to remove from combo box some options with clubs?

I tried:

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
```

and

```
def __init__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
```

Models:

```
class Club(models.Model):

    #Id keys
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True);

    #fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name=_('Name'));

    **reporter**=models.ManyToManyField(User,limit_choices_to = {'is_superuser': False}, blank=True,null=True,verbose_name=_('Reporters:'),related_name="reporter_club")


class Report(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)

    date=models.DateField(_("Date"), blank=False);

    league=models.ForeignKey(League, verbose_name=_('League'))

     **club1**=models.ForeignKey(Club,  related_name='club1',verbose_name=_('Club1') )
```

If you take look on image:
[link with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rfhN.png)
you can see that in club1 is list with all possible clubs, I need just clubs where reporter is defined as reporter, not all.

Here is my admin.py for model Reporter:

```
class MatchReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = PictureFormMatchReport

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):

        fields='date', 'league', 'group'
        media_description=('picture',)

        #'headline','picture','goals','team_formation','match_report'
        return [
            (None, {'fields':fields }),
            (None, {'fields': (('club1','club2'),), 'classes': ['wide', 'opened']}),
            (None, {'fields': (('result1','result2'),('break_result1','break_result2'),)}),
            (None, {'fields': ['headline','picture', 'goals','team_formation','match_report']}),

               ]



    list_display = ('custom_date','league','group','reporter','headline','custom_match_report')



    list_filter = ('date','league','group','headline')

    search_fields = ('date','league__league','group','headline')

    save_as = True



    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            reporter = User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk)
            obj.reporter=reporter
            obj.save()

        # Django always sends this when "Save as new is clicked"
        if '_saveasnew' in request.POST:
            # Get the ID from the admin URL
            original_pk = resolve(request.path).args[0]
            # Get the original object
            original_obj = obj._meta.concrete_model.objects.get(id=original_pk)

            # Iterate through all it's properties
            for prop, value in vars(original_obj).iteritems():
                # if the property is an Image (don't forget to import ImageFieldFile!)
                if isinstance(getattr(original_obj, prop), FieldFile):
                    setattr(obj,prop,getattr(original_obj, prop)) # Copy it!

            # find and add reporter pk
            reporter = User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk)
            obj.reporter=reporter
        obj.save()

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        res = super(MatchReportAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return res
        return res.filter(reporter=request.user)

admin.site.register(Report,MatchReportAdmin)
```

Comment: Please update answer with full models.py and try to explain the exact problem you are having with any relevant code. How do you currently remove clubs in your project? What is the problem with your current implementation? The more specific you can be the more we can help.

Comment: Is the image for a view or the built in django admin? Can you post your admin.py or view.py code for this please.

Comment: The image which I uploaded is from backend-django admin. In my first post is added admin.py for reporter. I still need a way how to remove some clubs from field club1.

Comment: I found solution here here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103672/django-admin-form-how-to-change-select-options-dynamically